# Code skips user input, executes code, and repromts after error check in java

Tags: java, boolean, java.util.scanner

Promting for a user to enter true or false for powersteering option to be added to a object later.

```
        for( i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        System.out.println("Please enter true for power steering else false:");
        powerSteering = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (powerSteering.equalsIgnoreCase("true") || powerSteering.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
            Boolean valueOf = Boolean.valueOf(powerSteering);
            i++;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Error");
            i--;
        }
    }
```

When executed it skips through taking user input from the system. Checks for an error through the if statements, and rempromts for user input where then the console allows it to be entered. I dont understand why it is or how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any `keyboard.nextInt()` calls (on any other calls that don't read a full line) prior to this loop?

Comment: @Eran That's could really be the problem. `nextInt/Double..` doesn't consume the end of line character.

Comment: Yep thats it lol... I need some coffee.